# ffmpeg - extract multi-line subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm extracting a subtitle using:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:4 outsub.ass`

It works fine at first glance:

```
Dialogue: 0,0:02:46.24,0:02:47.88,Default,,0,0,0,,y que eliminamos por la orina.
Dialogue: 0,0:02:48.20,0:02:50.24,Default,,0,0,0,,ﾂｿQuﾃｩ le has estado preguntando
Dialogue: 0,0:02:50.28,0:02:52.88,Default,,0,0,0,,Como tenemos aquﾃｭ
Dialogue: 0,0:02:52.92,0:02:55.76,Default,,0,0,0,,que es una enciclopedia,
Dialogue: 0,0:02:55.80,0:02:58.56,Default,,0,0,0,,cuando comemos espﾃ｡rrago
```

The problem is that the actual subtitle is this:

[screenshot showing two lines of subtitle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMyBO.jpg)

It seems there are two lines of subtitle and only one gets extracted.  There is a missing line after:

`Dialogue: 0,0:02:48.20,0:02:50.24,Default,,0,0,0,,ﾂｿQuﾃｩ le has estado preguntando`

Can anyone help me?  Besides a solution, maybe educate me in why the two lines of sub are so high above each other?  Almost like a couple of new lines in between.

Kind regards and thanks in advance.